# How do you access the benefits from Amazon Prime to get free Kindle books?

Tags: kindle, kindle-app, amazon-prime

I have downloaded the Kindle app to an IPad, and I just about get locked in having to try and get Kindle Unlimited, which I do not want.  I am an Amazon Prime customer.  And, I understand such customers have access to millions of free book titles.  But, when I look up books I never see any info suggesting a book is free using Kindle with Amazon Prime.  I only see that certain books are free with Kindle Unlimited.  Can anyone clarify this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon has two types of eBook subscription services
1.  Kindle Unlimited
2.  Kindle Owner's Lending Library

Differences:
[image]

The books available to each service are both around 1.4 million titles.

Amazon Prime members can borrow ONE book each calendar month from the Kindle Owner's Lending Library.  This link has a good video of how to search the Kindle Owner's Lending Library... https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=help_search_1-1?ie=UTF8&nodeId=200757120&qid=1360282925&sr=1-1&tag=bom-tomsguideca-20

Also, Amazon Prime members have access to the Amazon Kindle First Picks Program for free. Meaning, you have the option to download one of six editor's picks made available before their publication date each month, for free.  This option does not carry over each month. https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=201376210&tag=bom-tomsguideca-20

For an additional fee of $99 a year or $10.99 a month, you can have full access to the Kindle Owner's Lending Library.  Alternatively, for an additional $2.99 you can get FreeTime Unlimited which gives you access to ~ 13,000 kid friendly books, tv shows and games.

Here is a quick overview of your Amazon Prime Benefits:
https://www.tomsguide.com/us/what-is-amazon-prime,news-18041.html

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [Amazon Prime reading](https://www.amazon.com/kindle-dbs/fd/nonprime-pr).
With this, you can borrow 10 books at a given time, provided you're Prime member.

Note: Prime Reading doesn't provide all the books. But it's good enough to be read.

Comment: The first answer that is well documented contradicts your own.